# porting randomID function from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Okay, so I'm trying to create a backend to a system I've developed in JS/Node; the issue I'm having is that my `generateID` function can't seem to be replicated in PHP correctly?

The JS function is:

```
// To make id smaller we get microseconds count from more recent date
var start = Date.UTC(2012, 12, 21, 12, 0, 0, 0) * 1000

// Prefix with number, it reduces chances of collision with variable names
// (helpful if used as property names on objects)
  , prefix = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))

// Make it more unique
  , postfix = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36).toString(36)

  , abs = Math.abs;

module.exports = function (time = now()) {
    return prefix + abs(time - start).toString(36) + postfix;
};
```

The PHP version that I've tried to replace is:

```
$start = strtotime('2012-12-21 12:00:00');
$prefix = (string)(floor(rand() * 10));
$postfix = base_convert(floor(rand() * 36), 10, 36);
return $prefix.base_convert(abs(time() - $start), 10, 36).$postfix;
```

The results I'm getting a largely different, with Node I can get ID's such as **31ztgtlke4ga** but in the PHP version I'm getting **156094750003e9y5v2zjh700**

Comment: Why people try to make idGenerator complicate like this? You will never be sure that the id is unique. Just create some random string and check if it allready exist in your db. If it exist just repeat this action

Comment: Just use an open-source UUID generation library.  It'll do a better job and produce results in an industry-standard format

Comment: for generating unique id you don't have to go through that much trouble. you can user time() in php and var d = new Date(); var n = d.getTime(); in javascript. It provides you the unix timestap for the current moment, it will always be unique and easy to handel.
reset it's your wish but its always smart to keep it simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print the sample result.

```
$start = strtotime('2012-12-21 12:00:00', time());
$prefix = rand(0, 10);
$postfix = base_convert(rand(0, 36), 10, 36);


echo $prefix.base_convert(abs(time() - $start * 1000) * 1000, 10, 36).$postfix;
```

Javascript random and php rand function is different.
Javascript random generates a float value between 0 and 1, though php generates an integer value between min and max which are given as parameters.

Hopes this solution helps you.

By the way there's one mistake you made.

In your js code,

```
var start = Date.UTC(2012, 12, 21, 12, 0, 0, 0) * 1000
```

this line is incorrect.

Date.UTC function generates a millisecond-based timestamp which is same as Date.now() function.

You can remove * 1000. In this case you have to remove * 1000 too in the php code.

So php line will be look like this.

```
echo $prefix.base_convert(abs(time() - $start) * 1000, 10, 36).$postfix;
```

Comment: please add all relevant information to the answer by editing it